# In-lined Javascript blocks not initialized

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile

On a jQuery page, I have a login form. The code is simple enough:

```
<form method="post">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        .... Form here
    </div>
</form>
```

but the following form is submitted, JQM loads the next page via Ajax POST.

The problem is that any in-line Javasctipt on that new page is NOT initialized. I'm not talking about the $(document) elements etc. the entire in-lined Javascript blocks aren't initialized.

However if I add

```
data-ajax="false"
```

to the form tag, everything is fine. The page is loaded and initialized correctly.

Why does this happen, and is there a way to trigger a page initialization with the ajax loaded content?

I've observed this on both Firefox and the Android Webview clients.

Comment: Inline javascript inside a HTML document loaded with ajax will normally not be executed, there should be hundreds of duplicates of this if you use the search function.

Comment: I did look, but didn't find anything that explains why, and how to overcome this, short of using rel="external" and data-ajax="false"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason **`data-ajax="false"`** worked in your case is because it will force a full page reload which will incidentally trigger page markup enhancement.

This is a segment from jQuery Mobile documentation:

> It's important to note if you are linking from a mobile page that was
>   loaded via Ajax to a page that contains multiple internal pages, you
>   need to add a rel="external" or data-ajax="false" to the link. This
>   tells the framework to do a full page reload to clear out the Ajax
>   hash in the URL.

Now in your case if you want to enhance new page content use this:

```
$('#pageID').trigger('create');
```

or in case you have also made changes to header and footer use this:

```
$('#pageID').trigger('pagecreate');
```

If you want better understatement take a look at my blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, were I am talking about page content markup enhancement in great details. There you will find examples for functions mentioned on top. It can be also found **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**.

Answer (score 1):

If you load your page with the default jQuery Mobile implementation (which utilizes ajax), only the script blocks on the first page (`<div data-role="page">`) will get loaded.

You can turn off ajax loading via mobileinit which will disable ajax loading globally or you can disable it via the source link.

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});
```

or

```
<a data-role="button" data-ajax="false"
    href="myPageWithItsOwnScriptBlock.html">Link</a>
```

If you want to continue using ajax loading, you can place the script block inside of you "page" `<div>`

```
<div data-role="page">
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    <div data-role="header">
    ....
```

Details here:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to encapsule your inline JS code into something like this:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    // your inline code goes here
});
```

Comment: No use if the script block containing this isn't executed at all.