# jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I was wondering how can I enhance dynamically jQuery Mobile page?

I have tried to use these methods:

1. `$('[data-role="page"]').trigger('create');`

   and
2. `$('[data-role="page"]').page();`

Also how can I prevent enhancement markup of check boxes only?

Comment: What happened when you did .trigger('create') on an element that contained the elements you wanted to enhance?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

### Intro:

There are several ways of enhancing dynamically created content markup. It is just not enough to dynamically add new content to **jQuery Mobile** page, new content must be enhanced with classic **jQuery Mobile** styling. Because this is rather processing heavy task there need to be some priorities, if possible **jQuery Mobile** needs to do as less enhancing as possible. Don't enhance whole page if only one component need's to be styled.

What does this all means? When page plugin dispatches a **pageInit** event, which most widgets use to auto-initialize themselves. it will automatically enhance any instances of the widgets it finds on the page.

However, if you generate new markup client-side or load in content via Ajax and inject it into a page, you can trigger the create event to handle the auto-initialization for all the plugins contained within the new markup. This can be triggered on any element (even the page div itself), saving you the task of manually initializing each plugin (listview button, select, etc.).

With this in mind lets discuss enhancement levels. There are three of them and they are sorted from the less resource demanding to higher ones:

1. Enhance a single component/widget
2. Enhance a page content
3. Enhance a full page content (header, content, footer)

### Enhance a single component/widget:

> **Important:** The below enhancement methods are to be used only on current/active page. For dynamically inserted pages, those pages and their contents will be enhanced once inserted into DOM. Calling any method on dynamically created pages / other than the active page, will result an error.

Every **jQuery Mobile** widget can be enhanced dynamically:

1. [**Listview**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/) :

Markup enhancement:

```
    $('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

Removing listview elements:

```
    $('#mylist li').eq(0).addClass('ui-screen-hidden');
```

Enhancement example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LrAyE/

*Note that the refresh() method only affects new nodes appended to a list. This is done for performance reasons.*

One of a listview high-points is a filtering functionality. Unfortunately, for some reason, jQuery Mobile will fail to dynamically add filter option to an existing listview. Fortunately there's a workaround. If possible, remove current listview and add another one with a filer option turned on.

Here's a working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15163984/1848600

```
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
        $('<ul>').attr({'id':'test-listview','data-role':'listview', 'data-filter':'true','data-filter-placeholder':'Search...'}).appendTo('#index [data-role="content"]');
        $('<li>').append('<a href="#">Audi</a>').appendTo('#test-listview');
        $('<li>').append('<a href="#">Mercedes</a>').appendTo('#test-listview');
        $('<li>').append('<a href="#">Opel</a>').appendTo('#test-listview');
        $('#test-listview').listview().listview('refresh');
    });
```

2. [**Button**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/)

Markup enhancement:

```
    $('[type="button"]').button();
```

Enhancement example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/m4rjZ/

One more thing, you don't need to use a input element to create a button, it can be even done with a basic div, here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/L9xcN/

3. [**Navbar**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/navbar/)

Markup enhancement:

```
    $('[data-role="navbar"]').navbar();
```

Enhancement example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/w4m2B/

Here's a demo how to add dynamic navbar tab: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/V6nHp/

And one more in **pagebeforecreate** event: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/SJG8W/

4. [**Text inputs, Search inputs & Textareas**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/textinput/)

Markup enhancement:

```
    $('[type="text"]').textinput();
```

Enhancement example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/9UQ9k/

5. [**Sliders & Flip toggle switch**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/)

Markup enhancement:

```
    $('[type="range"]').slider();
```

Enhancement example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/caCsf/

Enhancement example during the pagebeforecreate event: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NwMLP/

Sliders are little bit buggy to dynamically create, read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15708562/1848600

6. [**Checkbox & Radiobox**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/controlgroup/)

Markup enhancement:

```
    $('[type="radio"]').checkboxradio();
```

or if you want to select/deselect another Radiobox/Checkbox element:

```
    $("input[type='radio']").eq(0).attr("checked",false).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

or

```
    $("input[type='radio']").eq(0).attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Enhancement example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/VAG6F/

7. [**Select menu**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/select/)

Markup enhancement:

```
    $('select').selectmenu();
```

Enhancement example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/dEXac/

8. [**Collapsible**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/)

Unfortunately collapsible element can't be enhanced through some specific method, so trigger('create') must be used instead.

Enhancement example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ck6uK/

9. [**Table**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/table-reflow/)

Markup enhancement:

```
    $(".selector").table("refresh");
```

While this is a standard way of table enhancement, at this point I can't make it work. So instead use trigger('create').

Enhancement example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Zqy4n/

10. **[Panels](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/panels/)** - *New*

Panel Markup enhancement:

```
    $('.selector').trigger('pagecreate');
```

Markup enhancement of *content dynamically added* to Panel:

```
    $('.selector').trigger('pagecreate');
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/PRC8W/

### Enhance a page content:

In case we are generating/rebuilding whole page content it is best to do it all at once and it can be done with this:

```
$('#index').trigger('create');
```

Enhancement example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/426NU/

### Enhance a full page content (header, content, footer):

Unfortunately for us trigger('create') can not enhance header and footer markup. In that case we need big guns:

```
$('#index').trigger('pagecreate');
```

Enhancement example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/DGZcr/

This is almost a mystic method because I can't find it in official **jQuery Mobile** documentation. Still it is easily found in **jQuery Mobile** bug tracker with a warning not to use it unless it is really really necessary.

Note, **.trigger('pagecreate');** can suppose be used only once per page refresh, I found it to be untrue:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/5rzxJ/

### 3rd party enhancement plugins

There are several 3rd party enhancement plugins. Some are made as an update to an existing method and some are made to fix broken jQM functionalities.

- **Button text change**

Unfortunately cant found the developer of this plugin. Original SO source: [Change button text jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009524/change-button-text-jquery-mobile/7279843#7279843)

```
    (function($) {
        /*
         * Changes the displayed text for a jquery mobile button.
         * Encapsulates the idiosyncracies of how jquery re-arranges the DOM
         * to display a button for either an <a> link or <input type="button">
         */
        $.fn.changeButtonText = function(newText) {
            return this.each(function() {
                $this = $(this);
                if( $this.is('a') ) {
                    $('span.ui-btn-text',$this).text(newText);
                    return;
                }
                if( $this.is('input') ) {
                    $this.val(newText);
                    // go up the tree
                    var ctx = $this.closest('.ui-btn');
                    $('span.ui-btn-text',ctx).text(newText);
                    return;
                }
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/mwB22/

### Get correct maximum content height

In case page header and footer has a constant height content div can be easily set to cover full available space with a little css trick:

```css
#content {
    padding: 0;
    position : absolute !important; 
    top : 40px !important;  
    right : 0; 
    bottom : 40px !important;  
    left : 0 !important;     
}
```

And here's a working example with **`Google maps api3`** demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7kGdE/

This method can be used to get correct maximum content height, and it must be used with a **pageshow** event.

```
function getRealContentHeight() {
    var header = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='header']:visible");
    var footer = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
    var content = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
    var viewport_height = $(window).height();

    var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();
    if((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
        content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
    } 
    return content_height;
}
```

And here's a live jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/nVs9J/

There's one thing to remember. This function will correctly get you maximum available content height and at the same time it can be used to stretch that same content. Unfortunately it cant be used to stretch img to full content height, img tag has an overhead of 3px.

### Methods of markup enhancement prevention:

This can be done in few ways, sometimes you will need to combine them to achieve a desired result.

- Method 1:

It can do it by adding this attribute:

```
    data-enhance="false"
```

to the header, content, footer container.

This also needs to be turned in the app loading phase:

```
    $(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled=true;
    });
```

***Initialize it before jquery-mobile.js is initialized (look at the example below).***

More about this can be found here:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/UZwpj/

To recreate a page again use this:

```
    $('#index').live('pagebeforeshow', function (event) {
        $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = false;
        $(this).attr('data-enhance','true');
        $(this).trigger("pagecreate")
    });
```

- Method 2:

Second option is to do it manually with this line:

```
    data-role="none"
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LqDke/

- Method 3:

Certain HTML elements can be prevented from markup enhancement:

```
     $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
          $.mobile.page.prototype.options.keepNative = "select, input";
     });
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/gAGtS/

***Again initialize it before jquery-mobile.js is initialized (look at the example below).***

### Markup enhancement problems:

Sometimes when creating a component from scratch (like listview) this error will occur:

> cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization

It can be prevented with component initialization prior to markup enhancement, this is how you can fix this:

```
$('#mylist').listview().listview('refresh');
```

### Markup overrding problems:

If for some reason default jQuery Mobile CSS needs to be changed it must be done with **`!important`** override. Without it default css styles can not be changed.

Example:

```css
#navbar li {
    background: red !important;
}
```

**`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vTBGa/

### Changes:

- 01.02.2013 - Added a dynamic navbar demo
- 01.03.2013 - Added comment about how to dynamically add filtering to a listview
- 07.03.2013 - Added new chapter: **Get correct maximum content height**
- 17.03.2013 - Added few words to the chapter: **Get correct maximum content height**
- 29.03.2013 - Added new content about dynamically created sliders and fix an example bug
- 03.04.2013 - Added new content about dynamically created collapsible elements
- 04.04.2013 - Added 3rd party plugins chapter
- 20.05.2013 - Added Dynamically added Panels and contents
- 21.05.2013 - Added another way of setting full content height
- 20.06.2013 - Added new chapter: **Markup overrding problems**
- 29.06.2013 - Added an important note of WHEN to use enhancement methods

Comment: @Gajotres Excellent Explaination

Comment: Wish I could add +6, this is the best answer I've seen in a long time.  Thank you very much for this, now only if the documentation for jQuery mobile was this straight forward.   THANK YOU!

One question though, I have a header that I'm changing... is there a like method for a header?  $(":jqmData(role='header')").header()?

Comment: If you want to enhance header you need to use trigger('pagecreate'), you can find it in my answer.

Comment: I want to enhance a input-field with type="password"
If i try $("#acntNewPW").textinput(); I get the classic style and behind that the new jquery mobile style.

Comment: This usually occurs when jQuery Mobile js is missmatched with jQuery Mobile css. Go to their official page and download latest versions and try again.

Comment: I want to enhance a embed-video from youtube.
If i show the page on the pc with IE it works but If i show the embed video on android or iOS it will not be on the screen.

Comment: Keep in mind to enhance using id if you don't want every widget to be enhanced.

Comment: Just to add, for dynamic [control groups](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/controlgroup-dynamic/), you want to do `$('.selector').controlgroup(  );` after the initial creation, and then `$('.selector').controlgroup( 'refresh' );` if you added anything. Cheers!

Comment: Very thorough and thorough! Question, though: is it a problem to call `$('#index').trigger('create');` if #index has jQuery Mobile controls that have been already been enhanced? I've experimented with this and it appears to me that it causes no problems... does it?

Comment: It will not cause any problems, it will only enhance new content.

Comment: Yep, very excellent, but its that's Disclosure, not a Disclaimer.  A Disclaimer would be something like, Hey, if you use the code here and it breaks your app, it's not on me.

Comment: Impressively in-depth, thanks for the work!

Comment: Ah well, it was a "shitty" framework (back then I did like it a lot) and these questions were asked on a daily basis. I had to write all-encompassing answer to cover everything.

Answer (score 4):

From JQMobile 1.4 you can do .enhanceWithin() on all the children http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/

```
var content = '<p>Hi</p>';
$('#somediv').html(content);
$('#somediv').enhanceWithin();
```

Comment: Is this preferable to `$('#somediv').trigger('create')`, and if so, why?

Comment: .trigger( "create" ) has been deprecated. You can use the new method .enhanceWithin() instead. For example, if you dynamically add a collapsible with an ul with data-role="listview" inside, you could use .enhanceWithin() to initialize the listview plugin.

Comment: Is it a problem to call this method on an element whose children have already been enhanced?

Comment: Im not aware of such problem. However this method goes though all the children of the selector and tries to enhance whatever it can find. Traversing big chunks of DOM in some cases is not the fastest thing to do...