# JQuery Mobile, losing formatting when programmatically changing button text

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, button, dynamic, formatting

I am attempting to programmatically change the text of a button in jQuery Mobile. When I do this the button loses some formatting. Below is code illustrating two attempts. Can any one suggest a way to do this that isn't going to jam up the browser?

```
<script>
$(document).bind("pageinit", function(){

    $("#buttonId").text("New Text");
    $("#buttonId").button("refresh");
});

//Method #2
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buttonId").text("New Text");
    $("#buttonId").button("refresh");
});
</script>

<a  id="buttonId" href="" data-role="button">Old Text</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be used:

```
$("#buttonId span span").text("New Text");
```

to change a text, there's no need for:

```
$("#buttonId").button("refresh");
```

Also in the future don't use: **`$("#buttonId").button("refresh");`**, this function is used only to enhance dynamically created/expanded listview look.

Correct way is :

```
$("#buttonId").button();
```

Button don't have a refresh method. If you want to find more about this and why is it important to be careful when working with a dynamically created content in jQuery Mobile take a look at my blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**. Or you can find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**.

Comment: Worked great, thanks! Is span span reffering to the html tag? Is that because jQuery Mobile adds those tags when the page compiles?

Comment: When jQM creates a button it will enhance its markup with additional span tags. You can check it using firebug addon on Firefox or Chrome.