# PhoneGap jQueryMobile listview not displaying correctly on secondary pages

Tags: jquery, listview, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing a PhoneGap app with jQueryMobile. My problem is the `listview` is not displaying correctly on the albums page, but is on the home page. I am using the same `data-theme` for both.

**Question:** Why is the listview on the second page not displaying correctly (background, font, icon)?

**Research:**

1. [jQueryMobile documentation on thumbnail listviews (what I'm trying to accomplish)](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html)
2. [jQueryMobile documentation on `listview` api](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html)
3. [Google searched and found a tutorial on how to do this (no change)](http://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2012/02/08/jquery-mobile-tip-adding-thumbnails-and-icons-to-list-views/)

**Code for album page**

```
    <div data-role="page" id="albums" data-url="albums" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true">Back</a>
            <h1>Albums</h1>
            <button id="albums-refresh">Refresh</button>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="albums-content" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery function to dynamically populate the `listview`**

```
Load: function () {
    $("#albums-content").empty();
    $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=356541460&entity=album", data: {get_param: "results"}, dataType: "json", success: function (data) {$.each(data, function (index, element) {$.each(this, function (index, element) {if (element.wrapperType === "collection") {$("#albums-content").append("<li><a id='a-" + index + "' href='#album-details'><img src='" + element.artworkUrl100 + "' />" + element.collectionName + "</a>"); $("#a-" + index).bind('click', function (index) {Albums.AlbumID = index; }); }}); }); }});
}
```

**PhoneGap Debug:**

[image]

**Album page** *Note that the purple background and orange text is not there, though you can see a faint hint of the `listview` drop shadow below the second album.*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easy solution for this problem (next time look further into jQM documentation).

When object is dynamically created in the **`jQuery Mobile`** listview its markup also needs to be enhanced like this:

```
$('#some-listview').listview('refresh');
```

Basically every time dynamic content is added to jQuery Mobile page it needs to be manually enhanced. If you want to find more about this topic please take a look at my blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**. Or you can find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**.

Comment: You all posted the exact same thing! Thank you, I completely forgot about calling refresh.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you have to make sure : after appending all the content to your list view you will have to add the following code

```
$("ul#albums-content").listview("refresh");
```

This is to update the styles and create any nested lists that are added.

Comment: You all posted the exact same thing! Thank you, I completely forgot about calling refresh.

Answer (score 2):

In the success function of your ajax call you need to call the refresh method for the listview element in order for the UI to be updated and rendered correctly.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-methods.html

Comment: You all posted the exact same thing! Thank you, I completely forgot about calling refresh.