# JQuery mobile not styling user input check item to same as the rest of list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-mobile

I have finally succeeded in being able to add user input items to a check list. However, when they are added they are not taking on Jquery Mobiles style.

This is a screen shot of what is happening

[image]

This is the HTML:

```
<h3>My items</h3>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="checkbox65">
        <input name="checkbox65" class="checkbox65" type="checkbox" />
          My stuff
      </label>
    </td>
 </tr> 
 <tr>
   <td>
     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
       <label for="textinput4">
         Add new item
        <input name="new_item" id="textinput4" placeholder="" value="" type="text" />
       </label>
     </fieldset>
   <button id="add">Add</button>
   /td>
  </tr>
  </table>​
```

This is the script for adding the user input item to the check list:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '#add', function(e) {
   var $this = $(this);
   var $firstRow = $this.closest('table').find('tr:first');
   var $newRow = $firstRow.clone();

   var input = $newRow.find(':input').remove();
   input.prop('checked', false);
   $newRow.empty().append(input).append('&nbsp;' + $('#textinput4').val());

   $newRow.insertAfter($firstRow);
  });
</script>
```

I read on a different question that perhaps I could include

```
$('[type='submit']').button();
```

in order to style the user input items. However, I am unsure if this is right for me or where I would put this in my script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should be used:

```
$('[type="checkbox"]').checkboxradio();
```

If you want to find out more about this and how dynamically added content can be correctly styled take a look at my blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, there you will find everything about enhancing dynamically added jQuery Mobile content. Or you can find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**.

Comment: Thank you. What line should I replace? or should I add it under the "input.prop" line?

Comment: Add it after it is appended.

Comment: `$newRow.empty().append(input).append('&nbsp;' +       $('#textinput4').val());
$('[type="checkbox"]').checkboxradio();`

doesn't do anything, while

`$newRow.empty().append(input).append('&nbsp;' + $('[type="checkbox"]').checkboxradio());`

results in [object name] being added the list..

Comment: Do not append $('[type="checkbox"]').checkboxradio(); add it into a new line after $newRow.insertAfter($firstRow);

Comment: Mm it made a difference however it now looks like this
[link](http://imgur.com/fcOL9V4)

Comment: Show me the output of this variable: $newRow

Comment: Umm this is printed to the console 

`[tr, prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1], context: button#add.ui-btn-hidden, constructor: function, init: function, selector: ""…]`

Comment: `<div class="ui-checkbox"><input name="checkbox65" class="checkbox65" type="checkbox"></div>&nbsp;new item`

Comment: It should look like this:     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" class="custom" /><label for="checkbox-1">I agree</label>

Comment: So this is just a matter of changing the HTML in my form above the add button? Thanks for all your help Gajotres

Answer (score 0):

At first sight you code has a jQuery syntax bug, it should look like this:

```
$('[type="submit"]').button();
```