# Need to restart app..Using Phonegap with lawnchair

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, lawnchair

I need to restart my app everytime I insert,delete or update my data.
Data is inserting and deleting properly...but dont know why i need to restart my app everytime to get the effect.

I want to use the file structure for this app.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/lawnchair.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/dom.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(e) {

        var details = Lawnchair({name:'details',adapter:'dom'},function(e){
            //this.nuke();
        });

        details.all(function(data){
            for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++)
            {
                //alert(data.length);
                var id = i + 1;
                //alert(id);
                document.getElementById("id").value = id;
                var listdiv = document.createElement('li');
                listdiv.setAttribute('id','listdiv' + i);
                listdiv.innerHTML = "ID : " + data[i].value.id + " | " + "Name : " + data[i].value.name + " | " + "Desc : " + data[i].value.desc;
                $('#show_list').append(listdiv);
            }
        });

        $('#save').click(function(e){
            //alert($.now());
            var obj1 = {id:$('#id').val(),name:$('#name').val(),desc:$('#desc').val()};
            //alert("listdiv" + obj1.id);
            details.save({key:"listdiv" + obj1.id,value:obj1});
            alert("Data Saved Successfully");
            //location.reload();
        });

        $('#del').click(function(e){
        if(document.getElementById("name").value != "")
        {
            var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
            details.remove("listdiv" + id,function(obj1){
                $("input:text").val("");
                document.getElementById("show_list").innerHTML = "";
                alert("Data Removed Successfully");
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please Select Data");
            return false;
        }
        });

        $('li').live('click',function(e){
            //alert(this.id);
            details.get(this.id,function(obj){
                document.getElementById("id").value = obj.value.id;
                document.getElementById("name").value = obj.value.name;
                document.getElementById("desc").value = obj.value.desc;
            });
        });
    });
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What effect, what is achieved with restart?

Comment: whatever i have inserted or deleted/updated is being achieved..

Comment: This was not my question, my question is what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to reflect the data in my li tags as soon as i modify or insert a new data...i dont want to restart my app to get the reflection..

Comment: <div>
    <ul id="show_list">
    </ul>
<div>

Comment: So you want to jQuery Mobile to restyle your dynamically added content? If this is a case it can be easily achieved.

Comment: yes.. due to that i dont have to restart my app again n again.

Comment: Give me a minute to write you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because new content has been appended code should look like this:

```
    details.all(function(data){
        for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++)
        {
            //alert(data.length);
            var id = i + 1;
            //alert(id);
            document.getElementById("id").value = id;
            var listdiv = document.createElement('li');
            listdiv.setAttribute('id','listdiv' + i);
            listdiv.innerHTML = "ID : " + data[i].value.id + " | " + "Name : " + data[i].value.name + " | " + "Desc : " + data[i].value.desc;
            $('#show_list').append(listdiv);+
        }
        $('#show_list').listview().listview('refresh');
    });
```

This line has been added (**`#show_list`** should be listviews id) :

```
$('#show_list').listview().listview('refresh');
```

If you want to find more about this (how to enhance dynamically added content in jquery Mobile) take a look at my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**. Or it can be found **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)** in my other answer. Read it carefully because there are numerous ways how his can be achieved.

**EDIT :**

And here's a fix for your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/3cuPP/

When you click save button you also need to append new data. In your case I have used all function to get all data, that same data is then appended to listview and refreshed.

Comment: getting a error. Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: then try this: $('#show_list').listview().listview('refresh');

Comment: Also carefully read my other article, this error was described there.

Comment: Can you put this new line after for loop?

Comment: Ok lets do it in a different fashion. Problem with jQuery Mobile is that it hates usage of this syntax $(function(e) { or document ready to initialize a code. All jQuery mobile page handling should be done inside proper page event. Can you tell me id of a page you are using to hold a listview? Worst case scenario do you have a live example or can you send me your code and I will make it work.

Comment: page id is "page"..can i get your mail id to send you the whole code?? or should i put it on jsfiddle and give you the link???

Comment: Whole code, Sorry in hurry paste all in javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/Aakash_Jain/LbFUr/

Comment: You will find it in my profile, but I can also write it here: dragan.gaic@gmail.com

Comment: its ok...forwarded you the jsfiddle link above you can check whole code there.

Comment: I have found another problem, listview refresh was not enough. When you save new data you must also trigger details.all function. If you take a look it is only triggered at a begging but not when save is pressed.

Comment: i already tried calling it after saving data...but problem persists.. let me check it once again doing this...

Comment: it is showing data after saving it but just for 1 seconds. again page automatically gets refresh and data get disappears.. again have to restart app to see data...showing but for a second only..

Comment: Are you talking about your or my example? In my example everything works fine. When you add data it is saved and displayed in listview, nothing disappears after that.

Comment: thanks Gajotres...very thankfull to you...i m new to stackoverflow and u helped me in my very first post...cnt thank you enough brother...