# Jquery dynamic list generation

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

```
for(var i=0; i< vendors.length;i++)
    {
     var $ul = $("<ul>").attr("data-role", "listview")
                .attr("data-divider-theme","a")
                .attr("data-inset","true")
                .appendTo("#vendorLists");
         $("<li>").attr("data-role", "list-divider")
                .attr("role","heading")
                .text(vendors[i])
                .appendTo($ul);
       for(var j=0; j<coupons[i].length; j++)
        {
            var x = coupons[i][j].split(":");           
            var $li = $("<li>").attr("data-theme", "a")     
                       .appendTo($ul);
            $("<a>").text(x[0] + ":" + x[1])
                       .appendTo($li);
            }
    }
```

I am using this code to create a list dynamically by fetching from a array.
vendorList is a div tag

The Jquery isnt coming on these..only the text is being displayed
Plz help

Comment: What does it mean for the jQuery to be coming on?

Comment: have you wrapped code inside script tag.?

Comment: yes..its under script tag...jquery graphics are not loading..only text  is being displayed

Answer (score 0):

You mention `vendorList` is a div tag.  However, you use `appendTo("#vendorLists")` in your definition of `$ul`.  Unless you meant `vendorLists` is a div tag, then you want to use `appendTo("#vendorList")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you add a dynamic content to the **`jQuery Mobile`** page you need to trigger a specific function meant to enhance page markup.

In your case it is this function:

```
$('[data-role="listview"]').trigger('refresh');
```

If you want to read more about that (with live **`jsFiddle`** examples) take a look at my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)** about this topic. Or it can be found **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**.