# Should I use jQuery Ajax api in jQueryMobile?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, jquery-mobile, web

I am making a Mobile web application, with HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, and jQueryMobile and warping it with `Phonegap`.

I am new in all the web thing, and I was wondering, when I use the jQueryMobile for the UI, can I use the jQuery api for Ajax calls, or does jQueryMobile has it's own tools for that.

I need to use Ajax, to interact with an external web-service, I will be fetching(get) and updating(get/post) from a database.

In other words, does the jQueryMobile supports all the jQuery api, or do I have also to include the jQuery separately in my application.

Comment: Warping it? On purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery function **`$.ajax`** is standard when creating an **`AJAX`** call with **`jQuery`** / **`jQuery Mobile`**.

Working **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/jLdFj/

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){ 
    $.ajax({url: "http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/json/23afca60ebf72f8d88cdcae2c4f31866/The Goonies",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: 'successCallback',
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        },
        success: function (result) {
            ajax.parseJSONP(result);
        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
        }
    });         
});
```

Few things to consider:

- **`$.ajax`** call should not be used during the page transition because possible page flickering
- All data dynamically generated through **`AJAX`** call must be afterwards enhanced to a **`jQuery Mobile`** page markup, here's my blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)** regarding this topic. Or it can be found **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**.
- When displaying dynamically generated content it must be appended during the correct page event, best one is **`pageboforeshow`** event. To find more about **`jQuery Mobile`** page events take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**.

Comment: In my application, do I need to Include both jQuery, and jQueryMobile? Or jQueryMobile file, contains all the jQery Apis?

Comment: NDakotaBE is correct, you need to use both of them, normally jQuery must be used first. Also you must understand not every jQuery version will be compatible with jQuery Mobile. For example, current stable jQuery Mobile 1.2 should be used with jQuery 1.8.3 and it will NOt work with version 1.9.1 and higher.

Comment: That is strange, do you know what is the reason behind that. When you mean use together, what is exactly that you mean? If I am making the UI with jQueryMobile and add the jQuery for ajax calls?

Comment: You cant use jQuery Mobile without jQuery, basically jQuery Mobile has an dependency on jQuery.

Comment: You can event test this, open my jsFiddle example and unselect jQuery from screen top left corner.

Comment: Yea is true, it is like that. Do you have any idea as to why newer version of jQuery wont work with the Mobile version of jQuery. Can I consume any kind of data with ajax, e.g., photos, and so on. In case I need to upload a photo to my database through the web-service.