# jQuery Mobile setting an attribute of a ListView

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, attributes

'Ello StackOverflowers.

So this is my scenario:
I populate a `ListView` using `localStorage`. Everything working populating that listview and "refreshing" it. BUT!

Now I want to add a search bar if more than 5 elements are added to the `ListView`. This is my current code (which is not working):

```
if (resultLength > 5)
{
    // alert('5 or more elemnts found.');
    $("#ConnectionList").attr("data-filter", true);
    $("#ConnectionList").attr("data-filter-placeholder", "Search...");
}
```

When I uncomment the `alert`, it fires correctly. Adding `.listview('refresh')` behind the two lines does not seem to work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not going to work. **`jQuery Mobile`** will fail to dynamically add filter to an existing listview.

But there's a workaround. Before you populate your listview count number of elements you are trying to populate, if number is 5 or more remove current listview and append new one at the same place. This is another strange thing, if you create a listview from scratch (with filter in mind), filter is going to be successfully generated.

I made an example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/SS7vJ/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $('<ul>').attr({'id':'test-listview','data-role':'listview', 'data-filter':'true','data-filter-placeholder':'Search...'}).appendTo('#index [data-role="content"]');
    $('<li>').append('<a href="#">Audi</a>').appendTo('#test-listview');
    $('<li>').append('<a href="#">Mercedes</a>').appendTo('#test-listview');
    $('<li>').append('<a href="#">Opel</a>').appendTo('#test-listview');
    $('#test-listview').listview().listview('refresh');
});
```

Also don't forget to call .listview( twice, first without refresh parameter, and second time with a refresh parameter. Without it you will receive this error:

```
cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization
```

You can find more about this problem in this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, to be transparent it is my personal blog. Or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**. Look for the chapter called: **Markup enhancement problems**.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Did it slightly different but the same approach (creating the ListView using jQuery instead of creating it in the HTML).