# jQuery Mobile -> Page Lifecycle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, page-lifecycle

Is there something like a lifecycle for jQuery Mobile pages? Like events that get fired on init, show, hide/back, or whatever events?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21):

## Intro

All information found here can also be found in my blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/page-events-order-in-jquery-mobile/)**, you will also find working examples.

### During the page transition:

**event** [**pagebeforecreate**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforecreate/)

**event** [**pagecreate**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/)

> Best event if you want to dynamically add page content and let jQuery
> Mobile style yout new content. Don't use it in case of ajax call,
> pagebefore show should be used then but all dynamically added content
> them must be manually [enhanced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600).

**event** [**pageinit**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/)

> It will only trigger once per page load, any return to the page will
> not trigger it again, unless page is manually refreshed

**event** [**pagebeforehide**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforehide/)

**event** [**pagebeforeshow**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeshow/)

> Best event for the page manipulation

**event** [**pageremove**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageremove/)

**event** [**pagehide**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagehide/)

**event** [**pageshow**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)

> Only event where other graphic jQuery/javascript can be initialized and used, like
> graph tools or carousels

### Rest of them:

**event** [**pagebeforechange**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforechange/)

> Will always trigger twice so skip it

**event** [**pagechange**](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechange/)

> Will always trigger twice so skip it

If you want to find more about this topic and how page events work overall take a look at my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**. Or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600)**.  Just search for the chapter called **Page events transition order**. But also read everything anywhere.

Official documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

Answer (score 1):

Just like Android activity lifecycle. jQuery Mobile pages have different `events`. You can check out the list of events from the official documentation for `jQuery Mobile 1.3.0`.

1. [pagebeforechange](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforechange/)
2. [pagebeforecreate](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforecreate/)
3. [pagebeforehide](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforehide/)
4. [pagebeforeload](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforeload/)
5. [pagechange](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechange/)
6. [pagechangefailed](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechangefailed/)
7. [pagecreate](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecreate/)
8. [pagehide](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagehide/)
9. [pageinit](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageinit/)
10. [pageload](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageload/)
11. [pageloadfailed](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageloadfailed/)
12. [pageremove](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageremove/)
13. [pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)

and much more jQuery Mobile events [documentation available here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/)

In my openion `pagebeforeshow`, `pageshow` and `pagecreate` are the commonly used events.