# Can some one please thoroughly explain the JQUERY MOBILE event cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dom

**Can someone please thoroughly explain the JQUERY MOBILE event cycle(pageinit,pagebeforeshow etc)?**
In what sequence are the events triggered and what is the state of the DOM before and after each event? In what situations should I listen to them?
What happens on refresh and hitting the back button?
I find some of the behavior very counter-intuitive and the documentation provided feels superficial and unclear.
 
*A diagrammatic explanation would be great!*
 
*If possible, please provide links to sources which can explain the concepts involved, in depth.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232532/jquery-mobile-page-lifecycle

Comment: This is a lot of questions bundled into one...a lot of which is already documented.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15929161/1771795