# jquery mobile listview: how to dynamically set themes for individual <li>'s

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, themes

I am using a jqm 1.3 Listview, and I am successfully capturing onClick.

```
  function handle_onClick( )
    { jQuery( "#my_panel li" )
        .each( function( )
             { jQuery( this ).attr( 'data-theme' , "a" ).trigger('refresh') ;
             }) ;
   }
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kC3bD/)
(**EDIT:** [updated  fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kC3bD/3/))

BUT the data-themes of the `<li>`'s are not being updated.

In practice my `<li>`'s will **not** be using the same theme.

Is there a way to pro-grammatically change them, individually?

Comment: What is `gf_Lc_handler__set_li_themes` in your fiddle ? Also where are you wiring up `handle_onClick`?

Comment: sorry, I saved the fiddle before I changed that ... "gf_Lc_handler__set_li_themes" is supposed to be "handle_onClick"

Comment: I updated it ... notice how it does not refresh the individual items until you do a mousemove event following the click event.

Comment: Your fiddle is still not updated.

Comment: You need to click "Set as base" to merge it into the original link. Problem with your code is that it sets every li to the new theme. Take a look at my answer how to do it individually.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/YNYnU/

```
$('#my_panel li' ).on( 'click' ,  function( argo_e ) { 
    $(this).attr('data-theme','d');
});
```

You were using wrong function to enhance listview markup. In this case we don't need to enhance listview markup, setting data-theme attribute to the correct li element is more then enough.

Also take a look at my other answer/article about this topis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600. Every jQuery Mobile component has a distinct function used to enhance its markup, and every one of them is listed in that article.

And here's example of your code with my fix: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/AeBuV/

Comment: when I click, the <li>, the theme is not immediately updated, but rather it only updates once I mouseout of the <li>

Comment: yeah it seems that no matter what I do, the <li>'s do not update their visual appearance until I mouseover/out of them individually ... hmmm

Comment: On what platform are you testing this?

Comment: it seems that the issue is that, although the theme is being updated, the actual class does not get updated UNTIL a mouseover/out event ... so I am working on that now.

Comment: Sry I meant what browser are you using. My style updates during the first click.

Answer (score 1):

the key is to:

- remove ui-btn-up-### and ui-btn-hover-### classes, using regex to pick them out of the long class string that jqm creates,
- then addClass( ui-btn-up-NEW_THEME) ,
- then update data-theme

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kC3bD/10/) :

```
function handle_onClick( argoj_element , args_language_id )
  { 
    jQuery( "#my_panel li" )
      .each( function( )
        { var lvb_active = ( jQuery( this ).attr( 'data-lang_id' ) == args_language_id ) ;

          var lvs_theme_default = 'a' ; 
          var lvs_theme_active  = 'e' ;  
          var lvs_theme         = lvb_active ? lvs_theme_active : lvs_theme_default  ;

          var lvs_current_class  = jQuery( this ).attr('class')                   ;
          var lvs_removes        = lvs_current_class.match(/ui-btn-up-\w+/gi ).join( " " ) ;
              lvs_removes       += " "  ;
              lvs_removes       += (lvs_current_class.match(/ui-btn-hover-\w+/gi )||[]).join( " " ) ;
          var lvs_adds           = "ui-btn-up-" + lvs_theme ;

          jQuery( this ).removeClass( lvs_removes )  
                        .addClass   (  lvs_adds   ) 
                         .attr( 'data-theme' , lvs_theme ) ;  
         }) ;             
  }
```

Comment: This is excellent. However, I'd like a more baked-in approach. You just need to be able to update `data-theme` and `refresh` the list view.