# remove white space between the content and footer: mobile app using jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile app using jQuery Mobile and I'm getting a white space between the content and footer. How do I close this space?

[the site with the white at the bottom](https://mydevl.georgiasouthern.edu/devl/rthompso/GATA/home.html)

Comment: link provided isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 solutions to this problem.

1. If you can use same **`data-theme`** for both content and page container. Unfortunately it wont look nice because there will still be a visible difference between both of them
2. Don't use **`data-theme`** on container but always use it only on page div. Still not a best solution.
3. Resize your content so it fills available free space. Use this method:

   ```
   function getRealContentHeight() {
       var header = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='header']:visible");
       var footer = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='footer']:visible");
       var content = $.mobile.activePage.find("div[data-role='content']:visible:visible");
       var viewport_height = $(window).height();

       var content_height = viewport_height - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight();
       if((content.outerHeight() - header.outerHeight() - footer.outerHeight()) <= viewport_height) {
           content_height -= (content.outerHeight() - content.height());
       } 
       return content_height;
   }
   ```

Read more about this solution in my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)** (my personal blog), or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**, look for the chapter: **Get correct maximum content height**.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the color of the ui-page-theme-a in your style/css, so you wont recognize it

```
.ui-page-theme-a
{
    background-color: sameAsContent/Footer !important;
    border-color: sameAsContent/Footer !important;

}
```

Comment: even there's allready an answer given and the thread is old, i added this. because it was a workaround for me and this is the first link, if you google the problem.