# Vertically arrange divs on smartphone browser with scrollable centre div

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, html, css-float

I am  trying to arrange a group of divs on-top of each other. The top div must be static place in the top-left (width = 100%) and not affected by the vertical scrolling that the centre div will have. I works somewhat as I want, except that the container div also got a vertical scroll that I don't want. Now I have two overlapping vertical scrollbars, one for the container div and one for the centre. I also use JQuery mobile on the page if that could help me arrange the divs.

How can I make my centre div (id=scroll) the only div that is scrollable and have my top div (id=fixed) at a fixed position without a scrollbar (no overlap of vertical scrollbars) and not be affected by page scrolling?

```
<div id="conatainer" style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%">


    <div id="fixed" style="position: static; top: 0%; overflow: hidden; height: 50%">

        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height: 85% ;min-height: 180px">

        ...

    </div>  


    <div id="scroll" style="position: absolute; overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden; height: 50%">

    ...

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you just let jQuery Mobile do it for you?

Comment: If I knew how I could do that, I wouldn't have post the question. Thank for the hint ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard **`jQuery Mobile`** template with a fixed header and content that scrolls: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/yWTG2/

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>
            First Page
        </h3>
        <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">

    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>
```

And here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Rf7NA/

For a header to be fixed it needs **`data-position="fixed"`** attribute.

Also in case you **WANT** to use only a layout and not **`jQuery Mobile`** styling take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)** or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**: Search for the chapter: **`Methods of markup enhancement prevention`**.

Comment: I am using xhtml (Primeface Mobile 0.9.3) that is using jQuery mobile. How can add the not standard 'data-role' and 'data-position' attribute ?

Comment: What is a nonstandard 'data-role' and 'data-position' attribute in this case?

Comment: Maybe its only my editor that does not recognize that attributes, will add them and see what happens.

Comment: It is your editor. A lot of them dont know how to detect modern HTML5 data and aria attributes.

Comment: In  the fiddle example, I just added the `data-position="fixed"` to make the 'First Page' header static. Right ?

Comment: Yes, you can remove it and see what will happen. Same thing goes for a footer if you ever gonna use it.