# How create dynamically selectmenu in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to dynamically create a `select` element, but it isn't styled by jQuery Mobile. What is the correct way to achieve this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgulaev/qagHz/4/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a working **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/dEXac/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){    
    // Add a new select element    
    $('<select>').attr({'name':'select-choice-1','id':'select-choice-1'}).appendTo('[data-role="content"]');
    $('<option>').attr({'value':'1'}).html('Value 1').appendTo('#select-choice-1');
    $('<option>').attr({'value':'2'}).html('Value 2').appendTo('#select-choice-1');    
    // Enhance new select element
    $('select').selectmenu();
});
```

Also take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, there you will find different method of enhancing jQuery elements markup, or it can be found **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content/14550417#14550417)**.

Comment: First of all trigger('create') is used to rebuild whole content. You should use appropriate function like in my example. And don't use vanila javascript while working with jQuery.

Comment: Good advise. Why $('select').selectmenu(); worked and don't work $('#id_select').selectmenu()?

Comment: You can use $('#select-choice-1').selectmenu(); it will work just fine. This example was created in the other answer to be as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that this should also work: (example appends two options to show how to add options.

```
$('<select name="sl" id="sl" data-native-menu="false"><option value="clear">That I got</option></select>').appendTo("#output");
$('<option value="clear2">Another That I got</option>').appendTo("#sl");
$('select').selectmenu();
```

Answer (score 0):

this one works for me

```
$(document).on('change', "body", function(){
    $( ".ui-selectmenu" ).selectmenu();
});
```