# Apply JQuery mobile style on button after add the button programmatically by javascript code

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

When I try to add below jquery mobile button throw jquery code:

```
        // insert new button to bf div (breackfast div)
      $("#bf").html('<a href="FoodCat/FilterIndex?TimeId=2&CurDate=0" data-role="button" > Add new </a> ');
```

It doesn't imply the Jquery mobile style (data-role="button") ??

Below is the html:

```
  <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="i" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="e">
      <div data-role="collapsible">

        <h3> Breackfast   </h3>
                 <div id="bf"  style="margin:0 !important;padding:0 !important; display:inline !important"> 
             <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="i" ">
              <li>

                <input type="button" tabindex="@ViewBag.CurInt" id="bdelete" value="DeleteFood" onclick="bfd();"/>
                 </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
```

Below is the JQuery code (PLZ note: it call the service and do the delete, but the problem only in not render button as jquery mobile style)

```
               <script type="text/javascript">
                    function bfd() {
                       var fp = '/api/service?prsnIduser1&MealTime=2&CurDate='+ $("#bdelete").attr("tabindex");
                      $.ajax({
                            url: fp,
                            type: 'Delete',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            contentType: 'application/json;  charset=utf-8',
                        success: function () {

                          $("#bf").html('<a href="FoodCat/FilterIndex?TimeId=2&CurDate=0" data-role="button" > Add new </a> ');
                      $("#bf a").buttonMarkup();

                             });
                            }
                   </script>
```

I did many search on google and on stackoverflow, And unsuccessfully I attempt below but without resault :

```
        $("div[data-role=collapsible]").collapsible({refresh: true });
         // or even add :
           $("#bf").page();
          // or
           $("#bf a").buttonMarkup();
```

Comment: is this what you want to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/qYLVb/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to dynamically create a **`jQuery Mobile`** button and have it styled correctly.

Here's a working **`jsFiddle`** example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/m4rjZ/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){    
    // Add a new button element
    $('[data-role="content"]').append('<a id="button" href="FoodCat/FilterIndex?TimeId=2&CurDate=0" data-role="button">Button</a>');
    // Enhance new button element
    $('#button').button();
});
```

To find out more about how jQuery Mobile handles dynamically added content and how it can be enhanced take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**.

Here's a link to an official jQuery Mobile button **[documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button/)**.

Comment: I am realy sorry to inform you it doesn't work either, I had try this before!

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. If it is working in example it also must work in your case.

Comment: I don't want to bind it with 'pagebeforeshow', I want it to be done after anyone click on the button with id 'bdelete'

Comment: Then do it, pagebeforeshow event is here only to help example work. Only thing you need is $('#button').button(); Take a look at an example again, I have changed it, you can add buttons now through click on an another button.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a button widget "by hand" by calling the `button()` method, as Gajotres suggests.

However, if you want a generic solution that does not depend on the widget type, you can have jQuery Mobile "catch up" to new markup by triggering the `create` event on an ancestor element.

For instance:

```
$("#bf").html('<a href="FoodCat/FilterIndex?TimeId=2&CurDate=0" data-role="button">Add new</a>')
        .trigger("create");
```