# HandleBar template & jQuery mobile & Dynamic listviews

Tags: jquery, json, cordova, jquery-mobile, handlebars.js

I'm using jQuery, jQuery Mobile, Handlebar for this project

I have a courses page as below.

[image]

When I click on a course it shows a page as below which contains particular lessons for a course.

[image]

Above lessons are taken from a JSON I use Handlebar for this. Below is the Handlebar template.

```
<script id="lessontemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
        <li><a href="{{lesson}}">{{lessonname}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Below is the JS code which replace the template

```
("#mycourses").on('click','.mycourse',function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            var url = domainURL+'coursedata.php?callback=?';    
            $.getJSON( url, { courseid: $(this).data('courseid') }, function( data ) {

            var tmpl = $('#lessontemplate').html();
            console.log(tmpl);
            $('h1.coursename').html(data.coursename);
            lessontemplate = Handlebars.compile( tmpl );
            console.log(    lessontemplate(data.coursedetails) );
            $('ul#lessons').html( lessontemplate(data.coursedetails) );
            $.mobile.changePage("#coursedetails", {transition: 'slide'}); 

            });

        });
```

Then If I go to courses page and click on course, lessons are not shown correctly. It shows the below output.

[image]

1st click Console.log() outputs are as below

```
    {{#each this}}
        <li><a href="{{lesson}}">{{lessonname}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}

        <li><a href="1">Lesson Name 1</a></li>

        <li><a href="2">Lesson Name 2</a></li>

        <li><a href="3">Lesson Name 3</a></li>
```

2nd click Console.log() outputs are as below

```
    {{#each this}}
        <li><a href="{{lesson}}">{{lessonname}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}


        <li><a href="1">Lesson Name 1</a></li>

        <li><a href="2">Lesson Name 2</a></li>

        <li><a href="3">Lesson Name 3</a></li>
```

1st click Console.log() = 2nd click Console.log() but why don't I get the correct output 2nd time? Why does not 2nd time lessons are not shown correctly?

Comment: Do you only load lessons dynamically through JSON?

Comment: everything is loaded through a JSON. I use the same procedure.

Comment: Can you try to do one thing. After this line: $('ul#lessons').html( lessontemplate(data.coursedetails) ); put this line: $('ul#lessons').listview('refresh');

Comment: just tried. But I get this error ---> Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: Give `ul#lessons` a `data-role="listview"`

Comment: I have already given it.

Comment: Is `lessontemplate` intentionally not localized with `var`?

Comment: $('ul#lessons')listview().listview('refresh'); should fix this error

Comment: @Gajotres - +1 and thanks for the directions.

Comment: If you want to understand this better, take a look at my other article/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600

Comment: okay sure. started reading and +1 added already on the post. really good one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Gajotres -  Thanks for pointing me to the right direction.

What you have to do is

```
if ( $('ul#lessons').hasClass('ui-listview')) 
{
 $('ul#lessons').listview('refresh');
} 
else {
 $('ul#lessons').trigger('create');
}
```

Taken from docs.

> If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the
> refresh() method on it to update the styles and create any nested
> lists that are added. For example:
>
> $('#mylist').listview('refresh');
>
> Note that the refresh() method only
> affects new nodes appended to a list. This is done for performance
> reasons. Any list items already enhanced will be ignored by the
> refresh process. This means that if you change the contents or
> attributes on an already enhanced list item, these won't be reflected.
> If you want a list item to be updated, replace it with fresh markup
> before calling refresh.

## Update

[Gajotres answer on some other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content/14550417#14550417)