# Apply jquery mobile only a portion of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a sample page which we have design very well. Now, we need to use jquery mobile only a portion of our page. The problem is that, when I add jquery mobile it is messing all my UI stuff. Is there is a way to apply jquery mobile only a portion of page?

Comment: jQuery mobile should leave your UI allone unless you used the same data attribute names and values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways of achieving this, and you can find them in my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content/14550417#14550417)**. Search for chapter called: **Methods of markup enhancement prevention**.

And here's a short description with examples. There are several solutions and you will need to pick right one:

### Methods of markup enhancement prevention:

This can be done in few ways, sometimes you will need to combine them to achieve a desired result.

- **Method 1**:

  It can do it by adding this attribute:

  ```
  data-enhance="false"
  ```

  to the header, content, footer container.

  This also needs to be turned in the app loading phase:

  ```
  $(document).one("mobileinit", function () {
      $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled=true;
  });
  ```

  ***Initialize it before jquery-mobile.js is initialized (look at the example below).***

  More about this can be found here:

  http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/UZwpj/

  To recreate a page again use this:

  ```
  $('#index').live('pagebeforeshow', function (event) {
      $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = false;
      $(this).attr('data-enhance','true');
      $(this).trigger("pagecreate")
  });
  ```
- **Method 2**:

  Second option is to do it manually with this line:

  ```
  data-role="none"
  ```

  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LqDke/
- **Method 3**:

  Certain HTML elements can be prevented from markup enhancement:

  ```
   $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        $.mobile.page.prototype.options.keepNative = "select, input";
   });
  ```

  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/jjETe/