# Only applying jQuery mobile enhancement to a single block

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a wordpress site with a responsive theme that looks good on mobile devices. However, I have an advanced searchform which doesn't work well on mobile devices so I have built a custom form with jquery mobile that both works and looks good. This form is then presented if a mobile device is detected.

But alas! JQM makes lots of problem on the main content. There are severe styling issues, but even worse, links are made into ajax calls so pages don't load properly.

I have found lots of info on how to *exclude* certain elements eg. with `data-role="none"` or `data-enhance="false"` (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15676562/apply-jquery-mobile-only-a-portion-of-page) but this being Wordpress, it is really not feasible to change all those elements.

Instead, I would like to *only* apply JQM enhancement to the single block containing the search form.

How can I do that?

Edit: I can turn off auto-initializing with `autoInitializePage: false` but then how do I turn on JQM enhancements for the selected block?

Answer (score 0):

so it only concerns the styling of the form on mobile devices? 
Maybe it is enough to add some CSS in a media query?
e.g:

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px)
```

{
/*css for the form here */

}

Comment: No, unfortunately not. The inclusion of JQM affects the overall styling. Simply including the JQM css file affects the styling. I already use a media query for the form's own styling.