# Apply css to listview after adding list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I am adding elements to a list with JSON after I get the data I do the following :

```
success: function(data){          
  var list = $('#' + HTMLfieldName[index] + 'Ul');
  $.each(data, function() {
    newLi = document.createElement('li');
    ref = document.createElement('a');
    ref.innerHTML = this.description;
    ref.href = '#' + this.code;
    newLi.appendChild(ref);
   list.append(newLi);
   });          
}
```

This works fine, but the elements in the lists are show as normal href ( blue and underscore ) instead of the nice CSS used in the listview examples.

This is how the code looks after rendering :

```
<ul class="levelUl ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" name="famUl" id="famUl">
  <li><a href="#2930">Finishing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2910">Speciality Printing</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2900">Toner</a></li>
</ul>
```

If I paste that code in the HTML page it looks fine.

Do I need to execute something to apply the CSS after it has been added to the page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must trigger markup enhancement on dynamically added listview elements with:

```
$('ul#id').listview('refresh'):
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LrAyE/

Basically your code would look like this:

```
success: function(data){          
    var list = $('#' + HTMLfieldName[index] + 'Ul');
    $.each(data, function() {
        newLi = document.createElement('li');
        ref = document.createElement('a');
        ref.innerHTML = this.description;
        ref.href = '#' + this.code;
        newLi.appendChild(ref);
        list.append(newLi);
    });
    list.listview('refresh');    
}
```

And remember, you must call **`.listview('refresh');`** after the **`each`** loop.

To find out more, read my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content/14550417#14550417)**.