# How to programmatically create listview in JQM

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, jquery, jquery-mobile-listview

I have an array from ajax and i need to create [jQuery Mobile Listview](http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/). I don't found a method for this, so is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a  working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/SS7vJ/

And another example with an array: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/yHHWQ/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $('<ul>').attr({'id':'test-listview','data-role':'listview', 'data-filter':'true','data-filter-placeholder':'Search...'}).appendTo('#index [data-role="content"]');
    $('<li>').append('<a href="#">Audi</a>').appendTo('#test-listview');
    $('<li>').append('<a href="#">Mercedes</a>').appendTo('#test-listview');
    $('<li>').append('<a href="#">Opel</a>').appendTo('#test-listview');
    $('#test-listview').listview().listview('refresh');
});
```

Also don't forget to call .listview( twice, first without refresh parameter, and second time with a refresh parameter. Without it you will receive this error:

> cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization

If you want to find out more about how jQuery mobile handles dynamically added content and its markup take a look at this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, to be transparent it is my personal blog, or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**.

Comment: also found other method, looks like `.append(sites).trigger('create');`

Comment: I would advise you against trigger('create') cause it is resource heavy. While listview('refresh') will style only listview, trigger('create') will restyle whole page content. Read about that in a link at the end of my answer.