# JQuery Mobile sliders inserted dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery, jquery-mobile-slider

I'm inserting sliders dynamically. The problem it's that when I insert them dynamically they don't have the theme of jquerymobile.
Here's the code i use:

```
for (var i = array_colors_available.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        $('#insert_colors_slider').append('<div data-role="fieldcontain" ><fieldset data-role="controlgroup"> <label for="slider-8">'+array_colors_available[i]+' : '+'</label><input id=slider-'+i+' type="range" name='+array_colors_available[i]+' value="0" min="0" max="25" data-highlight="true" data-theme=c data-track-theme="f"></fieldset></div>');
        if(array_slider_info_value != null) $('#slider-'+i).val(array_slider_info_value[i+1].value);
    };
```

[image]

And if I use the methods of JQueryMobile then on the screen appear two sliders:

```
for (var i = array_colors_available.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        $('#insert_colors_slider').append('<div data-role="fieldcontain" ><fieldset data-role="controlgroup"> <label for="slider-8">'+array_colors_available[i]+' : '+'</label><input id=slider-'+i+' type="range" name='+array_colors_available[i]+' value="0" min="0" max="25" data-highlight="true" data-theme=c data-track-theme="f"></fieldset></div>');
        $('#slider-'+i).slider();
        if(array_slider_info_value != null) $('#slider-'+i).val(array_slider_info_value[i+1].value);
    };
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong? When I don't use the methods there's no theme and when I use it I have two sliders instead of one...
Thanks!

Comment: What are the `id`s of the generated sliders?

Comment: use `.slider("refresh");` to refresh sliders after creating them. `$('#slider-'+i).slider().slider('refresh');`.

Comment: @Jesse the id is a number 1,2,3...

Comment: @Omar It still appear 2 sliders...

Comment: I think it would be easier to troubleshoot if you recreated it in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just one of jQuery Mobile bugs. Also there's an error in your code, label must point to the correct slider, and in your example it is not a case.

Dynamic slider can be created in two ways, none of them includes **`slider()`** method:

### Example 1

Do it during the **`pagebeforecreate`** or **`pagecreate`** event.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/caCsf/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){    
    // Add a new input element
    $('[data-role="content"]').append('<input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" value="25" min="0" max="100"  />');
});
```

### Example 2

Do it during the **`pagebeforeshow`** or **`pageshow`** event and use **`trigger('create')`** to style sliders.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NwMLP/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){    
    // Add a new input element
    $('[data-role="content"]').append('<div data-role="fieldcontain"></div>');
    $('[data-role="fieldcontain"]').append('<fieldset data-role="controlgroup"></fieldset>');
    $('[data-role="controlgroup"]').append('<label for="slider-2">Slider 2</label>');
    $('[data-role="controlgroup"]').append('<input type="range" name="slider-2" id="slider-2" value="25" min="0" max="100"  />');
    // Enhance new input element, unfortunately slider() function is not goinf to work correctly
    //$('[type="range"]').slider();
    $('#index').trigger('create');
});
```

In this example, if we try to use **`slider()`** only everything will be style except the input box.

More about this and some other related stuff can be found in my other **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, or find it **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**.

Comment: Both examples throw a JavaScript Runtime Error (0x800c001c).