# jquery mobile header/footer

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, markup

I am having some no of jquery pages each having header and footer. How do i make it as single header and footer. (ie) Want to load the header/footer html files in the main page header/footer section.

Please advice.

Please find the page structure below....

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>Single page template</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/customScript.js"></script>  
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div id="hdr">
        <!--Need to include header.html-->
    </div>  
    <div data-role="content">   
        <!--Content-->
    </div>
    <div id="ftr">
        <!--Need to include footer.html-->
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: first of all, you should have JQM scripts and style sheet links in `<head>`.

Comment: I use **php** on my mobile devs with jQuery mobile with a **header.php** file and another **footer.php**. Then i call them with `<?php include 'inc/header.php'; ?>` on every needed file.

Comment: how the php will work in mobile...? can u please provide some code...

Comment: @Yesvinkumar PHP works in the server so it is independent of the front end. Anyhow I guess you should read some web development introductory concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>      
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
    <script>
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(){       
            $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role="header"]').load("header.html", function(){ 
                $(this).parent().trigger('pagecreate');
            }); 
            $.mobile.activePage.find('[data-role="footer"]').load("footer.html", function(){ 
                $(this).parent().trigger('pagecreate');
            });  
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">

        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**header.html**

```
<h3>
    Header
</h3>
```

**footer.html:**

```
<h3>
    Footer
</h3>
```

The trick here is to trigger **pagecreate** (not **create**) to style header and footer after content has been added through **load** function.

Read this [**article/answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600) to find a difference between

```
trigger('create')
```

and

```
trigger('pagecreate').
```

Basically, **pagecreate** will restyle whole page while **create** will style only content.

Comment: @Yesvinkumar, maybe you should mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hdr").load("header.html"); 
    $("#ftr").load("footer.html"); 
});
```

Comment: i used the same. But the styles are not updated even i add trigger('create'). Can u please provide some code samples if any...? Many Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

**Add header**

Checks if there is no header and then `.append()` the header `.before()` div `data-role=content`.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
 if ($(this).find('[data-role=header]').length == 0) {
   $('[data-role=content]').before('<div data-role="header"><h1>Page header</h1></div>');
   $('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');
 }
});
```

**Add footer**

Checks if there is no footer and then `.append()` the footer `.after()` div `data-role=content`.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
 if ($(this).find('[data-role=footer]').length == 0) {
  $('[data-role=content]').after('<div data-role="footer"><h1>Page footer</h1></div>');
  $('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentPage=$.mobile.activePage;

$('<div data-role="header" id="myheader">
        <a href="" >Home</a>
        <a href="" >Back</a>
    </div>').prependTo(currentPage).trigger('create');

$('<div data-role="footer" id="myfooter">
        <a href="">About Us</a>
    </div>').appendTo(currentPage).trigger('create');
```