# Jquery mobile - update button style

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, markup, jquery-mobile-button

If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the refresh() method on it to update the styles and create any nested lists that are added. For example:

```
$('#mylist').listview('refresh');
```

What code I need if I add buttons to the page and refresh the style.

Comment: Create a new button or change text? like this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/HkmyB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one:

```
$('buttonID').button();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/m4rjZ/

There's also another function called **buttonMarkup()**, it is used to change some already styled button properties, for example to change button icon:

```
$('buttonID').buttonMarkup({ icon: "star" });
```

Read more about it in my other article: **[jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**

And a link to an **[official documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/button)**.