# How to completely disable Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

We encounter the following problems with Jquery Mobile.
Our site is divided in a mobile and a fixed desktop site.
Both use the same database and php code. Only the templates are different.

On our mobile site we use Jquery mobile for a better user experience and that works fine. However we integrated a button "goto desktop".
This link should bring us back to our "normal" desktop site.
But there is the problem. In the desktop-site, Jquery mobile is still activated and it replaces drop down fields, input fields and make a complete mess of the desktop site.

We tried everything to disable JQM but nothing seems to work.

How we can switch from our mobile site template to the desktop site template and disable JQM completely when we are on the desktop template?

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: make the server-side decide if jquery mobile is included in the header, if it's not there, it won't be activated

Comment: Thank you very much Frederik for the response.

Answer (score 1):

There are few available solutions but only one will really do.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/NvEcW/

Few things are needed, first we need to set this:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
        $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
    });
</script>
```

it will give us an ability to programatically turn on/off content enhancement. If you already don't know this **mobileinit** event must be initialized before jQuery Mobile initialization but after the jQuery initialization. This must always be a part of a page.

There's one last step. When we want to move from mobile to desktop page we need to reload page and use this javascript:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#index', function(){ 
    $(this).attr('data-enhance','false');
});
```

**[Pagebeforecreate](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagebeforecreate/)** event is important because at this point content is still not enhanced and attribute **[data-enhance](http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/)** = false will prevent any further page enhancement. If you want to turn it on again just set attribute value to true.

If you want more solutions then take a look at my other answer, search for the topic *Methods of markup enhancement prevention* : **[jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great solution dear Gajotres!
I am going to try your solution and and come back with the results.
Maybe it can help many members more:-)

Comment: Hello Gajotres,  We tried your code but it is not working.  It only works on the same page.  What can be wrong?  Maybe we can try another solution?  We have now the fact that all the code on the desktop template is mixd with the JQM.  Thanks in advance!