# Style JQuery created button with JQuery Mobile CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

In my JQ Mobile project I am using JQuery to create a button and append it to a div:

```
      var input = '<input type="button" class="save_event" value="Save"/>';
      $('.event').append(input);
```

However, this button seems exempt from Jquery Mobiles styling - it just appears as a normal webkit button. Would anyone know of a way to allow JQM's CSS to style this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to do:

```
$('[type="button"]').button();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/m4rjZ/

If you want to find out more about styling of dynamically created jQM elements take a look at my other answer: **[jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**