# jquery select one item from li using class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I have a ul>li structure using jQuery Mobile that looks like this:

```
<div>
<ul  data-role="listview">
  <li><a href="#" class="FoodDrinkItem">Hamburger<p class="FoodDrinkPrice">$9.00</p></a></li>
  <li> <a href="#" class="FoodDrinkItem">Club Sandwich<p class="FoodDrinkPrice">$7.00</p></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to get the price of the item when I click the specific li.I would like to do this with classes because its easier to expand afterwards.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".FoodDrinkItem").click(function(){
        var price = $(".FoodDrinkPrice").text();
        $("#PopupFoodDrinkPrice").text(price);
    });
});
```

How can I take the className.text() of the **selected** li?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/VWkm9/

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul li', function(){ 
    alert($(this).find('.FoodDrinkPrice').text());
});
```

And you have 2 errors in your structure:

This:

```
<div data-role="listview">
<ul>
```

Should be this:

```
<div>
<ul data-role="listview">
```

**`data-role="listview"`** must be placed inside an **`ul`** tag, without it **`listview`** will no be styled properly.

And your p tag is not properly closed.

Comment: This seems to be working perfectly.Why though?Is `$(this)` means the selected item that i am asking for?Any good links for learning jQmobile would be appreciated.I will flag the question correct as soon as i can.

Comment: $(this) (or self) is a keyword which can be used in instance methods to refer to the object on which the currently executing method has been invoked. To find out more take a look at this link: http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/ . Now regarding links, your BEST solution currently is jQM official documentation here: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/ and api here: http://api.jquerymobile.com/ , everything else is to fragmented. Also take a look at my profile and my answers, I answer mostly jQM questions so there's a good chance you will find your answer there. :)

Comment: Also I would advise you to take a look at two of my other answers. First one talks about why you should not use document ready with jQuery Mobile and what is a proper replacement: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600 . Second one talks about jQM widgets and how to use they dynamically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this will do the trick:

```
$(this).find(".FoodDrinkPrice").text()
```

Comment: This could work too, but I’m not sure we are seeing all the code.

Comment: But i dont want the text() of all the li.Just the .FoodDrinkPrice.text() of the specific li.FoodDrinkItem

Comment: Have you noticed my edit? The find call will look for the price in the relevant li's decendants.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing a nonexistent class called `.price` in your code execution. You should give each `<li>` a unique ID and reference them by that.