# Jquery Mobile: created a button with JQuery, trying to attach click function to it

Tags: jquery, json, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am retrieving data from a remote server via JSON and attaching a button to it:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.mysite.com/jsond1.php',

          function(data){
          jsonObject=eval(data);
          day1content = jsonObject.json1;

          //APPEND TO DIV
          $('#showday1').append(day1content);
          //CREATE BUTTON, ADD VALUE FROM
          var input = '<input type="button" class="save_event" value="Save to My Program" />';
          //ATTACH BUTTON
          $('.event').append(input);
```

This works fine. But I want to attach an event to the button, ie:

```
$('.save_event').click(function() {
                            console.log("HERE");
                 });
```

and when I place this directly below the script above nothing happens. Would anyone know why this is occuring? Do I need to to something special with JQuery Mobile?

Comment: Are you getting JSON containing JSON, as you are using `eval` on the data? The `getJSON` method already parses the JSON for you.

Comment: Where are you putting the `click` function ? Have you tried execute it on console ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$(document).on('click','.save_event',function() {
    console.log("HERE");
});
```

If you want to find out more about even delegation you can find it here: [**link**](http://www.sitepoint.com/event-delegation-with-jquery/).

Also do not forget to enhance your button markup with this:

```
$('.save_event').button();
```

If you want to find out more read my other article about jQuery Mobile dynamic content enhancement: **[jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content/14550417#14550417)**

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('.event').on('click', '.save_event', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('testlink'); 
    console.log("HERE");
});
```

This will attach your event to any input within the `.event` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

More info here:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Really weird! Try commenting out `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Nope - alerts still ok, but still no console.log

Comment: yes I am. It also seems it no longer recognises 'this' as in alert($('this').html());

Comment: Try killing the Chrome process and restarting it?

Answer (score 0):

you just have to bind right AFTER the button was create.

For safety, and avoid multiple event listener on the same button, you have to unbind before ;)

```
$.getJSON('http://www.mysite.com/jsond1.php',
          function(data){
              var jsonObject = eval(data),
              day1content = jsonObject.json1;

              // APPEND TO DIV
              $('#showday1').append(day1content);

              // CREATE/ATTACH BUTTON + ADD VALUE FROM
              $('.event').append('<input type="button" class="save_event" value="Save to My Program" />');

              // FOR SAFETY, UNBIND CLICK BEFORE BINDING : AVOID MULTIPLE BINDING
              $('.event .save_event').unbind('click');

              // ATTACH EVENT TO BUTTON
              $('.event .save_event').click(function() {
                        console.log("HERE");
             });
       });
```