# jquery mobile - listview widget is not displaying for dynamic content

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I have a parent list (ul-li), while clicking the li from the list i am creating the new child list and adding it to a new page. I am getting the proper Jquery mobile's listview for child list for first time alone, if i click the same li or some other li from parent list, child list loading with out the JQM's listview widget. instead it is loading the normal list.

**Please find the Jsfiddle link -**
http://jsfiddle.net/gopijsf/BG2ZV/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="parentPage">
        <header data-role="header" data-theme="d">
            <h3>Parent</h3>
        </header>
        <div>               
            <ul id="sectionUlContainer" data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#" class="sectionItemClass">List1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sectionItemClass">List2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sectionItemClass">List3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="sectionItemClass">List4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
            <h3></h3>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="childPage">
        <header data-role="header" data-theme="d">
            <h3>Child</h3>
            <a href="#parentPage">Back</a>
        </header>
        <div id="childList"></div>
    </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.sectionItemClass').click(function(){
    var childWidget = '<ul id="childUlContainer" data-role="listview"><li>childList</li></ul>';
    $('#childList').html(childWidget);
    $.mobile.changePage('#childPage',{transition:'slide'});
});
});
```

Help me how to reload JQM's listview each time.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
$('#childUlContainer').listview('refresh');
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LrAyE/

Read more about it here in my other article: **[jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content/14550417#14550417)**

And here your code fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/uejY2/

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#parentPage', function(){     
    $(document).on('click','.sectionItemClass',function(){
        var childWidget = '<ul id="childUlContainer" data-role="listview"><li>childList</li></ul>';
        $('#childList').html(childWidget);
        $.mobile.changePage('#childPage',{transition:'slide'});
    });
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#childPage', function(){       
    $('#childUlContainer').listview().listview('refresh')
});
```

Comment: Thank you my dear friend, now it is working. the key for my problem is, $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#childPage', function(){       
    $('#childUlContainer').listview().listview('refresh')
});. Thank u so much :)

Comment: If this is your answer please accept it. And I am glad to help you.