# jquery mobile horizantal radio buttons in knock out template binding

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am trying to bind jquery mobile horizantal radio buttons using knock out teplate binding.

The fielsset in template looks like

```html
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="attr: {id:QuestionID+'_fld'},template:     {name:'optionTemplate', foreach: OptionList}">
  </fieldset>
```

and the option template looks like

```js
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="optionTemplate">  
   <input type="radio"  data-bind="attr: { id:OptionID+'_radio',value:OptionID, name: QuestionID+'_rd'}, checked:$parent.OptionId" /> 
   <label data-bind="text:OptionText, attr: {id:OptionID+'_optn', for : QuestionID+'_rd' }">  </lable>
</script>
```

I have tried

```js
 $('input[type=radio]').checkboxradio().trigger('create');
 $('fieldset').controlgroup().trigger('create');
```

Here my problem is that the mobile css is not applying to the fiedset.

Answer (score 1):

You must do this after the template has built your page or during the page initialization event, something like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#pageID', function(){ 

});
```

Page content can be enhanced ONLY when content is safely loaded into the DOM.

Second this do **`NOT`** mix **`refresh functions`** with **`trigger create`**. Either one or the other. **`Trigger create`** is used to enhance whole content, and it should **`NOT`** be used on single elements. No point in restyling whole page every time you add new content.

Basically you only want to use:

```
$('input[type=radio]').checkboxradio().checkboxradio('refresh');
```

or if first line throws an error:

```
$('input[type=radio]').checkboxradio();
```

and:

```
$('fieldset').controlgroup();
```

But I would advise you to only use this line after everything has been appended:

```
$('#contentID').trigger('create');
```

where **`#contentID`** is an id of your **`div data-role="content"`** object. Or in case you are not using content div, only **`data-role="page"`** div then use this:

```
$('#pageID').trigger('pagecreate');
```

where **`#pageID`** is an id of your page.

To find out more about marku enhancement of dynamically added content take a look at this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)**.

Comment: I have written.... $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#divPage', function(){    
        $('#divPage').trigger('pagecreate'); 
});  Radio buttons are horizantally displaying but css not applying