# Loading templates using jQueryMobile with Marionette

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to use JQM with Marionette but facing an issue.

Problem: I have an index.html page with empty divs with data-role="page" and "content". I have my underscore template file having just one label and button in JQM style.

So far I have succeeded in loading my template using Marionette.ItemView and Marionette regions. Everything's working great like loading of all required scripts like jQuery, JQM, Backbone.Marionette, loading of jQueryMobile css etc. And the view gets rendered successfully, along with label and the button.

But the problem is the theme which I set in my template to the div is not reflected and even the button or label UI is not that which is provided by JQM.

I think that after loading of templates I should refresh the page. But where and how I should do it in my code. I have tried lot of code but nothing is working.

This is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Index</title>
<!-- data-main attribute tells require.js to load config.js after require.js loads. -->
<script data-main="../js/apps/config" src="../js/ext_libs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">

    <header id="header" data-role="header"></header>

    <div id="main" class="container-fluid" data-role="content"></div>

    <footer data-role="footer" class="footer">
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my index_view

```
define([ "marionette", "templates" ], function( Marionette, templates ) {
console.log("Success..Inside Index View.");
var IndexView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template : templates.index_body({title: 'Worrrrrld', btn_submit: 'Submit'})
});
return IndexView;
});
```

And the template

```
<div data-theme="b" id="index_view">
<label><%= title %></label>
<input type="submit" value=<%= btn_submit %> />
</div>
```

My App.js file

```
define([ "jquery", 
     "underscore", 
     "backbone", 
     "marionette", 
     "index_view", 
     "header_view" ], function($,_,
    Backbone, Marionette, IndexView, HeaderView) {
'use strict';
console.log("Success...Inside App");
console.log("Success..Libraries loaded successfully.");

var app = new Marionette.Application();
console.log("Success..App Object Got Created.");

app.addRegions({
    header : '#header',
    main : '#main',
    footer : '#footer'
});
console.log("Success..Regions Added");

app.addInitializer(function() {
    console.log("Success..Creating Header View Object.");
    app.header.show(new HeaderView());
    console.log("Success..Creating Index View Object.");
    app.main.show(new IndexView());
});

app.on('initialize:after', function() {
    Backbone.history.start();
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){
    console.log("Success..I am triggering event");
    $('[data-role="content"]').trigger('create');
});

console.log("Success..Returning App Object.");
return app;
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content/14550417#14550417

Comment: Thanks for the reply..but can you please advice where should i place the code $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){   
    // Enhance new select element
    $('[data-role="content"]').trigger('create');
});

Comment: @Gajotres I tried placing in my app.js script as shown above. But didn't work please tell me I am very new in programming with Jquery and Marionette

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Nithalia

You can take look at [`jquerymobile-marionette`](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette). In there, to model JQM page,  Backbone.Marionette.Layout is used. You can see how template is loaded and rendered.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. but i have already referred that link..the difference is just that i am not using JQM Router apart from that everything is same but still not working...Please tell me some other options.

Comment: can you post your config.js?  Also in your index_view, it loads 'templates' where is coming from?

Comment: Hello Ming.. As suggested by you i referred that code you specified. It working perfect but can you please tell me that the approach used in helper.js is it Backbone code right..its not completely marionette...Is it at low level. I tried to implement layouts but now the templates which were visible earlier, now they vanished...I have posted my complete code on this location please check and let me know..ASAP

Comment: link to my code https://github.com/rachnakhokhar/jqm_requirejs_marionette_demo.git

Comment: Just forked yours.  few small changes to your code and posted a pull