# how can i make jquery mobile not render part of the dom?

Tags: html, dom, jquery-mobile, angularjs

I need to disable a submit button and innerText by using angularJS,
but jquerymobile wrap the input tag in div.
If I don't want the wraping,or render the by my self,how can i do that?

Comment: Can you please post some parts of the code you currently have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
data-role="none"
```

as an attribute on that button.

There are several other methods and you can find them **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14550417/1848600)** or **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**, just look for an topic: **Methods of markup enhancement prevention**

Comment: Thanks that's helpful,and $("#button").triger("create")  as well