# Make div within data-role="content" responsive

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm very new to developing mobile web apps with jQuery mobile.
I trying to make a [Roundabout](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/#/enableDrag) inside a data-role="content". The problem is, the Roundabout height is not responsive, it won't change accordingly the screen height. Can anyone help me?

Here is my html

```
<body>

<div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Main App</h1>
    </div>

    <div align="center" data-role="content" style="width: 100% !important; min-height:200px !important " id="blockCarousel">
        <ul id="idCarousel" data-role="listview">
//li items goes here through AJAX
        </ul>
<div id="animateTest" class>
    <p id="containerDesc" class="nameItem" ></p>
</div>

</div>
<a href="#" style="display:none" class="next">Next please</a>
<a href="#" style="display:none" class="prev">Prev please</a>


</div>
```

my CSS:

```
html{
position:relative !important;
text-align:center !important;
height:100% !important;
 }

 body{
//height:100% !important;
background: rgba(255,255,255,.4) !important ;
 }
 .roundabout-holder {
    list-style: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    height: auto !important;
    width: 75% !important;
    top: 0 !important;
  }

.roundabout-moveable-item {
    height: 80% !important;
    width: 60% !important;
    background-color: #ccc !important;
    border: 1px solid #999 !important;
top: 0 !important;

-moz-user-select: none !important;
-webkit-user-select: none !important;
-webkit-user-drag: none !important;
 }

.roundabout-in-focus {
    cursor: auto !important;
top: 0 !important;
  }


 #animateTest {
position: relative !important;
height: 10em !important;
text-align: center !important;
background: #123 ;
padding: 20px 10px !important;
width: 25% !important;
display: block !important;
color: #fff !important;
margin: 0 auto !important;
border-radius: 5px !important;
font-weight: bold !important;
  }
```

Comment: have you tried setting min-height and max-height values for .roundabout-holder? rather than setting height to auto?

Answer (score 2):

To understand this you need to understand how jQuery Mobile works. First because you didn't post your javascript I can only guess what you have done.

First if you are using document ready to initialize your javascript code don't do it like that. Document ready will usually trigger before jQuery Mobile content is properly enhanced inside a DOM. That's why it is important to use proper page events, mainly **[pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)** even because this is only event where proper page height can be calculated so when working with jQuery Mobile and 3rd party frameworks that require height (carousels, galleries.. ) always initialize them inside a **[pageshow](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/)** event.

To find out more about page events take a look at my blog **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)**, first half of an article should interest you.

You need this:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#pageID', function(){ 
   //Initialize your plugin here
});
```

Where **`#pageID`** is an id of your plugin holding page.

There could also be another problem. Your plugin height is restricted because of a content height. For some reason content height will never cover whole available page height, only part of it. There are several ways it can be done manually. Solutions can be found in my other answer: [jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content/14550417#14550417) just look for a chapter called: **Get correct maximum content height**.