# Refresh jQuery Mobile elements after adding them to the page using AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, mobile

I have a PHP script that will render three form elements for each item in a database. For example, its output could look something like this:

```
<!-- Entry 1 -->
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="1-name"></label>
<input type="text" name="1-note" id="1-note" data-mini="true" />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="1-age"></label>
<input type="text" name="1-note" id="1-note" data-mini="true" />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="1-description"></label>
<input type="text" name="1-note" id="1-note" data-mini="true" />
</div>  

...

<!-- Entry n -->
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="n-name"></label>
<input type="text" name="n-note" id="n-note" data-mini="true" />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="n-age"></label>
<input type="text" name="n-note" id="n-note" data-mini="true" />
</div>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="n-description"></label>
<input type="text" name="n-note" id="n-note" data-mini="true" />
</div>
```

Then on the main page, I use Ajax to add that php-generated content to the page...

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function(){
    $("#menu1").bind("change", function() {
        $.ajax({
             type: "GET", 
             url: "includes/ajax_get_entries.php",
             data: "table="+$("#menu1").val(),
             success: function(html) {
                 $("#wrap").html(html).selectmenu('refresh', true);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

... by putting the PHP content in between a wrapper:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" id="wrap"></div>
```

Adding it to the page works fine, but jQuery Mobile does not update the style.

How can I make it update the style?

I cannot use add the content to the site and hide if using .show() and .hide(), as I need a response from my user on which table I need to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call

```
$("#wrap").trigger('create');
```

in your success callback.

Also see this question [jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content)

Comment: Thanks. :-) Apparently, I also needed to remove ".selectmenu('refresh', true)" which resulted in an uncaughterror as selectmenu was not initialized.