# CSS will not apply to dynamically created elements in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I want to add dynamically generated list items to an unordered list in my jQuery mobile page.

But when I add new list items, the existing CSS isnt applied. sortedList is my ul.

Ive tried a few different things including:

```
jQuery('#sortedList').append('<li><h3>SUCCESS</h3></li>')

jQuery('#sortedList li').html('<h3>SUCCESS</h3>')

jQuery('#sortedList li').append('<h3>SUCCESS</h3>')

jQuery('#sortedList li').trigger('create');
jQuery('#sortedList li').append('<h3>SUCCESS</h3>')
```

Nothing works, any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Should work: http://jsfiddle.net/aaNMJ/

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/kkHKm/).

Comment: @LinkinTED the question is about jQuery mobile, not vanilla CSS. The title is poorly stated, but please read the details of the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content)

Comment: this question is answered 1000 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add all items to the list, then refresh the listview :

```
$('#sortedList').append('<li><h3>Success</h3></li>').listview('refresh');
```

[Here's a JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Xmh7k/)

As a sidenote: you don't have to spell out jQuery every time, to use jQuery. The `$` symbol is another name for the jQuery object, so `jQuery('#mySelector')` is equivalent to `$('#mySelector')`

Comment: Cheers mate, this works perfectly!

And Im aware of the $, but I have to use jQuery selector for this. Cheers though