# Running jQuery Mobile on only a section of a page by id?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

How to I apply jQuery Mobile only to a certain section of my page specified by element id?

Since it runs when the script is loaded, how do I limit it to only part of a page?

Comment: Show us the code - what do you mean, certain section of the page? Are you referring to `$("#my_element")`? That runs whatever functions you want only for the element with id `my_element`.

Comment: Download custom built of jquery mobile and then initialize widgets manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong then you want to apply `css` or `style` on certain `div` or another container.

Refer Below links.

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content) And [JQUERY MOBILE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)

I hope this both links will help you.