# Using Handlerbars with Yahoo Pipes

Tags: jquery-mobile, handlebars.js, yahoo-pipes

I'm trying to pull JSON feeds from a yahoo pipes source into my jQuery Mobile project using Handlebars.js with jQuery's ajax method.
This method works without Handlebars, but there are some limitations. It doesn't show up in jquerymobile listview format, instead it pops out like a normal bullet list. Here's the source:

```
var pipeURL = "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=mu3NkfY_3BGtncSIJhOy0Q&_render=json";

$.ajax({
    url : pipeURL,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var html = '<ul data-role="listview" id="all-posts-two" data-filter="" data-count-theme="c">';
        $.each(data.value.items, function(i, item) {
            html += "<li>" + item.title + "</li>";
        });
        html += "</ul>";

        //Add the feed to the page
        $("#PostsList").empty().html(html);
    }
});
```

Here's the source for the other method I've been trying to use with Handlebars but obviously I'm missing something somewhere.

```
    $.ajax({
    url : pipeURL,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data) {

        //line to check the received data on the console
        console.log(data);


        //handlebars area
        var source = $("#posts-template").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
        var blogData = template(data);
        $("#all-posts").append(blogData);
        $("#all-posts").trigger("create");
        dfd.resolve(data);

    },
    error : function(data) {
        // console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Here's the html source for the template

```
            <ul data-role="listview" id="all-posts" data-filter=""></ul>
            <script id="posts-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                {{#each value.items}}
                <li data-postid="{{ID}}">
                    <a data-transition="slide" href="#">
                        <p>{{{title}}}</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
                {{/each}}
            </script>
```

Anyone, please help me out please

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see you are using an older version of jQuery Mobile (lower then 1.4).

Do it like this:

```
var pipeURL = "http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=mu3NkfY_3BGtncSIJhOy0Q&_render=json";

$.ajax({
    url : pipeURL,
    dataType : "json",
    success : function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var html = '<ul data-role="listview" id="all-posts-two" data-filter="" data-count-theme="c">';
        $.each(data.value.items, function(i, item) {
            html += "<li>" + item.title + "</li>";
        });
        html += "</ul>";

        //Add the feed to the page
        $("#PostsList").empty().html(html);
        $('#all-posts-two').listview('refresh');
    }
});
```

Look at this line:

```
$('#all-posts-two').listview('refresh');
```

It will enhance dynamically added listview, of course there's one more thing, you need need to trigger it after whole dynamic list has been done and not on every li element, it will fail in this case. In your next example you are using this line:

```
$("#all-posts").trigger("create");
```

It will fail because **trigger('create')** is used to enhance whole **data-role="content"** not just part of it so as such it should be used only on **data-role="content"** div.

Read more about it in this other **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content/14550417#14550417)**.

Or take a look at my blog [**article**](http://www.gajotres.net/advanced-jquery-mobile-tutorial-part-2-client-server-communication/), there you will find a working example of listview created from remote JSON data.

### Update:

If you are using jQuery Mobile 1.4 try this line:

```
$('#all-posts-two').enhanceWithin();
```

**.enhanceWithin()** is method introduced in jQuery Mobile 1.4 to replace all other methods.

### Update 2

This question is finally answered in another **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23782061/loop-through-an-array-of-json-objects-using-handlebars/23782140?noredirect=1#comment36584900_23782140)**, or you can find it [**here**](http://www.gajotres.net/using-jquery-mobile-with-handlebars/) with working example:

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I'm using jQuery 2.0.3 and JQM1.4.0

Comment: I tried what you said, but it still shows up in a bullet list instead of the jQM listview format. Is there a chance you can please help out with the Handlerbars method

Comment: Also please look at your console and tell me are you receiving any errors?

Comment: Thanks again for your response. I just tried what you said, still the same bullet list format. And I have no errors on the console. Do you mind dropping a full source for the ajax() call.

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, I even created a working example from your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vds2U/39/

Comment: If you want you can mail me your code and I will fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks Gajotres, please drop your mail

Comment: dragan.gaic@gmail.com