# Asp.net mvc use Jquery mobile in partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have an asp.net mvc website.

I the layout, il load Jquery and Jquery Mobile.

Then, in my page that use the layout, I have a div :

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="home">
```

At some point, I load a partialView using Ajax, and replace the content of this div with the partialView html result :

```
$("#home").html(data);
```

In the partialView, I have :

```
<div data-role="header">
   header
</div>

<div data-role="content" id="MainContent">

</div>

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
footer
</div>
```

It loads the data correcly but only have the text, I have no Jquery mobile header/footer...

Do you have an idea why ?

EDIT : Thanks for the link. But I'm really a beginner and I didn't manage to get it work yet... Like my example is easy, could you tell me exactly what I have to do ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content/14550417#14550417

Comment: Read this answer to find out why.

Comment: Thanks. So I l looked "Enhance a full page content (header, content, footer)" right ? Where do I have to put "$('#home').trigger('pagecreate');" ?