# load dynamic values in form elements in jquerymobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I have one page called index.html.I need to load some values at the time of showing page via jquery mobileevent .

Text and text area values added well.But the filpbox is not updating.Can anyone please to solve this ?

inxedx.html filp box coding

```
<label for="group_name" class="ui-hidden-accessible"></label>
                <input type="text" name="group_name" id="group_name" placeholder="Enter Group Name" />
            <label for="group_desc" class="ui-hidden-accessible"></label>
                <textarea  name="group_desc" id="group_desc" placeholder="Enter Group Decription"></textarea>
<label for="group_published">Published</label>
                <select name="group_published" id="group_published" data-role="slider" data-theme="b">
                <option value="1" >Yes</option>
                <option value="0" >No</option>
                </select>
```

test.js

```
$('#pg_add-group').on('pageshow', function(event) {


            $('input[id=group_name]').val('hello');
            $('textarea[id=group_desc]').val('hello desc');
            $('select[id=group_published]').selected = false;

    $( ".input[id=group_name]" ).textinput( "refresh" );
    $( ".textarea[id=group_desc]" ).textinput( "refresh" );
});
```

Comment: What flip box? You mean Select box?

Comment: yes.but its data-role="slider"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to enhance look of select box, it is done like this:

```
$('select[id=group_published]').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Read more about it **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content/14550417#14550417)**.

### Update:

I didn't look carefully so I didn't so your question was about flipswitch slider.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vds2U/75/

#### HTML:

```
<label for="flip-1">Flip switch:</label>
<select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider" data-default-value="off">
    <option value="off" defaultSelected>Off</option>
    <option value="on">On</option>
</select>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', '#reset', function(){ 
        $("#flip-1").val('off').slider('refresh');
    });
});
```

Comment: its not working .I'm having a doubt with $('select[id=group_published]').selected = false;.will it work ?