# ajax json php callback lost css jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a web app, using Jquery Mobile, I have to make an Ajax/Json to a  PHP  to retrieve MySQL data, when I get the JSON Callback, and create the "list" from the array, the path of the jquery mobile css file get lost, and my  is not well formed. This is my code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "busca_reservas.php",
    data: "fecha=" + fecha + "",
    dataType: 'json',   
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        var output = '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="reservas" class="listareservas">';

        var logsData = data;
        for (var i in logsData.logs){
            regis  = logsData.logs[i].recid;
            nombre  = logsData.logs[i].nombre;
            ape     = logsData.logs[i].apellido;
            output+= '<li><a href="#">' + regis + "  " + nombre + " " + ape + '</a></li>';

        }
        output+='</ul>';

        $('.listareservas').listview('refresh');
        $("#result").append(output).fadeIn(500);

        console.log(output)
    }
});
```

The content in my  looks like plain text, instead of Jquery Mobile "List View".
Any help wil be welcome ?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jquery-mobile, but I'll bet the problem is that you're doing `refresh` _before_ you append the output the DOM. So it's not matching the new element you're adding. Just swap those two lines.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I tried that but I received the following error message "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'" , thanks

Comment: Then you also need to initialize jquery mobile on the new elements after appending them. Now my inexperience with this library leaves me unable to give the details, but maybe Jacob's answer is the clue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Mobile: Markup Enhancement of dynamically added content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `refresh` after the `append`:

```
    $("#result").append(output).fadeIn(500);
    $('.listareservas').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score -1):

I vaguely remember this issue when I was working on a jquery mobile project ahwile back. I basically came to this solution

```
function refreshLayout() {
    $("div[data-role=page]").page("destroy").page();
}
```

which I would call with every ajax success function.  You may have to modify the data-role portion to fit what needs to be refreshed in your project.  Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you guys, I found the answer to my problem in another post. I just add .trigger("create"); in my --> $("#result").html(output).fadeIn(500).trigger("create"); And its working fine ..