# How To Refresh New Div Content in Jquery Mobile 1.4.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm dynamically adding content to page div.

But i could not refresh to new content.The style is missing.(Only shows links)

I'm trying to add listview.

Here is my **popup.html**:

```
<div id="pageDiv" data-role="page" data-theme="a">
    <div id="contentDiv">
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my **popup.js**:

```
  $("#button").on("click",function(e){            

        var contentDiv = $("#contentDiv");
        contentDiv.empty();

        var wordDiv = '<ul id="wordListViewId" data-role="listview" data-split-icon="plus" data-split-theme="a" data-inset="true" style="height:15px;width:350px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;">' +
            '<li>' +
            '<a href="#"><h3 style="text-align: center;">' + 'try me' + '</h3></a>' +
            '<a id="minusId" href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>' +
            '</li>' +
            '</ul>';

        contentDiv.append(wordDiv);
    });
```

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content

Comment: @Saar i want to refresh whole div. not specific item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZg5J/384/)**.

You can use `.trigger( "create" )` :

```
contentDiv.append(wordDiv).trigger( "create" );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: no, i want to update div. div may contain lots of elements which might not be listview

Comment: What you mean by update div or refresh div? div not need refresh, append to the work, but for the list view you should refresh it after dynamic creation.

Comment: #contentDiv has lots of childs such as buttons,tables,listview etc. So i want to refresh contentDiv then all elements will appear

Comment: Just append add element to the div.

Comment: i did and i tried your code. nothing changed. i see links not listview :(