# Is it possible to use jQuery data-filter to filter items brought in from external HTMLl via .load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to use jQuery `data-filter` to filter items brought in from external HTML via `.load`?

I use jQuery's data-filter to allow users to filter lists, so that only list items which match their input are displayed.

```
<div data-role="content">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search..." data-inset="true">

    <li data-role="list-divider"> Characters </li>
    <li data-filtertext="apples:oranges">Group 1</li>
    <li data-filtertext="apples:bananas">Group 2</li>
    ...
    <li data-filtertext="monkeys:boxes">Group 200</li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

But, I want to move the list items to a separate html file, and call it using:

```
$("div[id^=menu]").each(function() {
  var match = this.id.match(/\w+$/)[0];
  $(this).load('menus/' + match + '.html');
```

So that I can replace all the list items with

```
<div data-role="content">
  ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search..." data-inset="true">

  <div id="menutest"></div>

  </ul>
</div>
```

On the index page, and have the lists in `menus/menutest.html`

At the moment, although this'll display the lists when index is loaded, they're just static on the page and it doesn't allow them to be filtered. Can this be done?

Comment: which plugin you use?

Comment: You need to call the filter function in the callback function of `.load()`.

Comment: Barmar, assuming I don't know what I'm doing 90% of the time - what would that look like?

Comment: Dekel, I don't think I'm using any plugin, just straight jquery and jquery mobile

Comment: *«assuming I don't know what I'm doing 90% of the time»* -- This is then you main problem. You should at least try to know what you're doing. **1)** Read aout how to append elements using [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) in order to add a `<div id="menutest">` element **2)** Read about [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to fill it.  --- For now, it looks like you try to call a load on inexistant "menutest" element. Not mentionning the `div` as direct child of a `ul` being invalid HTML...

Comment: <<This is then you main problem. You should at least try to know what you're doing>>. Thanks Louys Patrice Bessette. I'm still learning, which is why I'm asking questions. I've spent a lot of time trying different variations of code to get this to work, and only come here for help when I'm out of ideas. Usually, when I find a working peice of code, I can then go through it piece by piece and identify why it works and what it all means.

Comment: @Barmar I thin I need to do something like:  
<code>$("div[id^=menu]").each(function() {
    var match = this.id.match(/\w+$/)[0];
    $(this).load('menus/' + match + '.html', function() {
 listview('refresh');
})}}; </code>    but I'm clearly getting something wrong

Comment: Where is your code that does the filtering? jQuery doesn't know anything about `data-filter` by itself, so you're either using a plugin that processes it or you have your own functions to do the filtering.

Comment: @Barmar hmm I can't find any customised code that'd be relevant. It looks like data-filter is part of jquery mobile - would that be right?

Comment: You're right, it is part of jquery-mobile: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/filterable/

Comment: This question looks related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550396/jquery-mobile-markup-enhancement-of-dynamically-added-content